# Persistent in-memory Python object for nginx/uwsgi server

Tags: python, optimization, nginx, redis, uwsgi

I doubt this is even possible, but here is the problem and proposed solution (the feasibility of the proposed solution is the object of this question):



I have some "global data" that needs to be available for all requests. I'm persisting this data to Riak and using Redis as a caching layer for access speed (for now...). The data is split into about 30 logical chunks, each about 8 KB.

Each request is required to read 4 of these 8KB chunks, resulting in 32KB of data read in from Redis or Riak. This is in ADDITION to any request-specific data which would also need to be read (which is quite a bit).

Assuming even 3000 requests per second (this isn't a live server so I don't have real numbers, but 3000ps is a reasonable assumption, could be more), this means 96KBps of transfer from Redis or Riak in ADDITION to the already not-insignificant other calls being made from the application logic. Also, Python is parsing the JSON of these 8KB objects **3000 times every second.**



All of this - especially Python having to repeatedly deserialize the data - seems like an utter waste, and a perfectly elegant solution would be to just have the **deserialized data cached in an in-memory native object in Python**, which I can refresh periodically as and when all this "static" data becomes stale. Once in a few minutes (or hours), instead of 3000 times per second.

But I don't know if this is even possible. You'd realistically need an "always running" application for it to cache any data in its memory. And I know this is not the case in the nginx+uwsgi+python combination (versus something like node) - **python in-memory data will NOT be persisted across all requests** to my knowledge, unless I'm terribly mistaken.

Unfortunately this is a system I have "inherited" and therefore can't make too many changes in terms of the base technology, nor am I knowledgeable enough of how the nginx+uwsgi+python combination works in terms of starting up Python processes and persisting Python in-memory data - which means I COULD be terribly mistaken with my assumption above!



So, **direct advice on whether this solution would work** + references to material that could help me understand how the nginx+uwsgi+python would work in terms of starting new processes and memory allocation, would help greatly.

P.S:

1. Have gone through some of the documentation for nginx, uwsgi etc but haven't fully understood the ramifications per my use-case yet. Hope to make some progress on that going forward now
2. If the in-memory thing COULD work out, I would chuck Redis, since I'm caching ONLY the static data I mentioned above, in it. This makes an in-process persistent in-memory Python cache even more attractive for me, reducing one moving part in the system and at least FOUR network round-trips per request.

Comment: What does this data look like? How rigid is the structure? How often does it change?

Comment: Huge set of key-value pairs with some nesting involved. Sample structure (expressed as JSON): {key1: value1, key2:{subkey1: [value1, value2, value3], subkey2: value2}, key3: [value1, value2, value3]}. So a reasonable amount of variety in the data, but as I said it is fairly static and I can bear with updating it only every few minutes or even every 1 hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're suggesting isn't directly feasible. Since new processes can be spun up and down outside of your control, there's no way to keep native Python data in memory.

However, there are a few ways around this.

Often, one level of key-value storage is all you need. And sometimes, having fixed-size buffers for values (which you can use directly as `str`/`bytes`/`bytearray` objects; anything else you need to `struct` in there or otherwise serialize) is all you need. In that case, uWSGI's built-in [caching framework](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Caching.html) will take care of everything you need.

If you need more precise control, you can look at how the cache is implemented on top of [`SharedArea`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/SharedArea.html) and do something customize. However, I wouldn't recommend that. It basically gives you the same kind of API you get with a file, and the only real advantages over just using a file are that the server will manage the file's lifetime; it works in all uWSGI-supported languages, even those that don't allow files; and it makes it easier to migrate your custom cache to a distributed (multi-computer) cache if you later need to. I don't think any of those are relevant to you.

Another way to get flat key-value storage, but without the fixed-size buffers, is with Python's stdlib [`anydbm`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/anydbm.html). The key-value lookup is as pythonic as it gets: it looks just like a `dict`, except that it's backed up to an on-disk BDB (or similar) database, cached as appropriate in memory, instead of being stored in an in-memory hash table.

If you need to handle a few other simple types—anything that's blazingly fast to un/pickle, like `int`s—you may want to consider [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html).

If your structure is rigid enough, you can use key-value database for the top level, but access the values through a `ctypes.Structure`, or de/serialize with `struct`. But usually, if you can do that, you can also eliminate the top level, at which point your whole thing is just one big `Structure` or `Array`.

At that point, you can just use a plain file for storage—either `mmap` it (for `ctypes`), or just `open` and `read` it (for `struct`).

Or use `multiprocessing`'s [Shared `ctypes` Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects) to access your `Structure` directly out of a shared memory area.

Meanwhile, if you don't actually need all of the cache data all the time, just bits and pieces every once in a while, that's exactly what databases are for. Again, `anydbm`, etc. may be all you need, but if you've got complex structure, draw up an ER diagram, turn it into a set of tables, and use something like MySQL.

Comment: With mixed data (floats and strings) some general searches for benchmarks showed simplejson to be faster than cpickle. Which is why I was talking about the JSON example, and also "shelve" etc at the moment seem out of scope. And would reading from file actually be faster than hitting Redis - say on localhost? Of course, considering we're talking about roughly only 31KB of static data, it looks like it'd be hitting the disk cache again and again rather than hitting the spindle at all. "uwsgi's Caching" looks REAAALLLLYY interesting, and almost a perfect match, unless I run into some issues.

Comment: I suppose the uwsgi cache would be accessible "in-process" from Python and be naturally several-x faster than Redis. That seems about right, but just confirming to make sure my understanding of the ground rules here is correct.

Comment: At 32KB, the difference between shared memory, an `mmap`ed file, or `read`ing a file from "disk" (as you say, really the OS disk cache), etc. is probably not going to matter much. Sending it over a localhost TCP socket shouldn't add much either. (But obviously, test.) As for the JSON-vs.-pickle issue, if you've got just one level (a dict full of floats and strings), you wouldn't be storing mixed data; each value is just a simple float or string. But you don't; you've got a few levels, so… shelve is out.

Comment: Meanwhile, with a few levels of hierarchy, the wUSGI cache isn't an automatic win either. If you've got, say, 8 top-level keys, each with 2-8KB of data underneath them, it'll handle that pretty well (although it does mean you'll be using 64KB of cache rather than 32KB)—but the problem is, you still need to serialize into those 8KB buffers. If you can directly cast from a buffer into a `ctypes.Structure`, that's as fast as you'll get—but that often means, e.g., using an array of pairs instead of a dict, which means access to the values is linear (although with a pretty small N, it sounds like).

Comment: Oh, one more thing: If you have, say, 8 top-level keys, each with 2-8 second-level keys, … you could create 8 caches, each with 8 1K buckets (or maybe they still have to be 4K or whatever your page size is, I'm not sure…), which means you only need to serialize level 3 and below. At that point, you may have so little structure that even JSON is fine?

Comment: At this point, I'll really have to test and see what is the best combination of options that will result in the most efficient solution for me (considering the use-case). I'll mark this as the accepted answer and add further comments as I find out more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"python in-memory data will NOT be persisted across all requests to my knowledge, unless I'm terribly mistaken."

you are mistaken.

the whole point of using uwsgi over, say, the CGI mechanism is to persist data across threads and save the overhead of initialization for each call. you *must* set `processes = 1` in your `.ini` file, or, depending on how uwsgi is configured, it might launch more than 1 worker process on your behalf. log the `env` and look for `'wsgi.multiprocess': False` and `'wsgi.multithread': True`, and all `uwsgi.core` threads for the single worker should show the same data.

you can also see how many worker processes, and "core" threads under each, you have by using the built-in `stats-server`.

that's why uwsgi provides `lock` and `unlock` functions for manipulating data stores by multiple threads.

you can easily test this by adding a `/status` route in your app that just dumps a json representation of your global data object, and view it every so often after actions that update the store.

Answer (score 1):

You said nothing about writing this data back, is it static? In this case, the solution is every simple, and I have no clue what is up with all the "it's not feasible" responses.

Uwsgi workers **are** always-running applications. So data absolutely gets persisted between requests. All you need to do is store stuff in a global variable, that is it. And remember it's per-worker, and workers do restart from time to time, so you need proper loading/invalidation strategies.

If the data is updated very rarely (rarely enough to restart the server when it does), you can save even more. Just create the objects during app construction. This way, they will be created exactly once, and then all the workers will fork off the master, and reuse the same data. Of course, it's copy-on-write, so if you update it, you will lose the memory benefits (same thing will happen if python decides to compact its memory during a gc run, so it's not super predictable).

Comment: Whoa, necropost. Did not notice the date before. I wonder why SO decided to show me this post?

Answer (score 0):

I have never actually tried it myself, but could you possibly use uWSGI's [SharedArea](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/SharedArea.html) to accomplish what you're after?

Comment: You'd have to build a whole lot on top of that to make it usable. Basically, this gives you the same kind of API you get from a file object; that's it. As the "Warning" at the top of the page you linked says: "SharedArea is a very low-level mechanism. For an easier-to-use alternative, see the Caching and Queue frameworks."