# Flask-sqlalchemy / uwsgi: DB connection problem when more than on process is used

Tags: flask, heroku, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, uwsgi

I have a Flask app running on Heroku with uwsgi server in which each user connects to his own database. I have implemented the [solution reported here for a very similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877914/flask-sqlalchemy-on-the-fly-connections-to-multiple-databases). In particular, I have implemented the connection registry as follows:

```
class DBSessionRegistry():
    _registry = {}

    def get(self, URI, **kwargs):
        if URI not in self._registry:
            current_app.logger.info(f'INFO - CREATING A NEW CONNECTION')
            try:
                engine = create_engine(URI,
                                       echo=False,
                                       pool_size=5,
                                       max_overflow=5)
                session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
                Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
                a_session = Session()
                self._registry[URI] = a_session
            except ArgumentError:
                raise Exception('Error')

        current_app.logger.info(f'SESSION ID: {id(self._registry[URI])}')
        current_app.logger.info(f'REGISTRY ID: {id(self._registry)}')
        current_app.logger.info(f'REGISTRY SIZE: {len(self._registry.keys())}')
        current_app.logger.info(f'APP ID: {id(current_app)}')

        return self._registry[URI]
```

In my `create_app()` I assign a registry to the app:

```
app.DBregistry = DBSessionRegistry()
```

and whenever I need to talk to the DB I call:

```
current_app.DBregistry.get(URI)
```

where the `URI` is dependent on the user. This works nicely if I use uwsgi with one single process. With more processes,

```
[uwsgi]
processes = 4
threads = 1
```

sometimes it gets stuck on some requests, returning a 503 error code. I have found that the problem appears when the requests are handled by different processes in uwsgi. This is an excerpt of the log, which I commented to illustrate the issue:

```
# ... EVERYTHING OK UP TO HERE.
# ALL PREVIOUS REQUESTS HANDLED BY PROCESS pid = 12
INFO in utils: SESSION ID: 139860361716304
INFO in utils: REGISTRY ID: 139860484608480
INFO in utils: REGISTRY SIZE: 1
INFO in utils: APP ID: 139860526857584
# NOTE THE pid IN THE NEXT LINE...
[pid: 12|app: 0|req: 1/1] POST /manager/_save_task => 
generated 154 bytes in 3457 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 4 headers in 601 
bytes (1 switches on core 0)
# PREVIOUS REQUEST WAS MANAGED BY PROCESS pid = 12
# THE NEXT REQUEST IS FROM THE SAME USER AND TO THE SAME URL.
# SO THERE IS NO NEED FOR CREATING A NEW CONNECTION, BUT INSTEAD...
INFO - CREATING A NEW CONNECTION
# TO THIS POINT, I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY IT CREATED A NEW CONNECTION.
# THE SESSION ID CHANGES, AS IT IS A NEW SESSION
INFO in utils: SESSION ID: 139860363793168    # <<--- CHANGED
INFO in utils: REGISTRY ID: 139860484608480
INFO in utils: REGISTRY SIZE: 1
# THE APP AND THE REGISTRY ARE UNIQUE
INFO in utils: APP ID: 139860526857584
# uwsgi GIVES UP...
*** HARAKIRI ON WORKER 4 (pid: 11, try: 1) ***
# THE FAILED REQUEST WAS MANAGED BY PROCESS pid = 11
# I ASSUME THIS IS WHY IT CREATED A NEW CONNECTION
HARAKIRI: -- syscall> 7 0x7fff4290c6d8 0x1 0xffffffff 0x4000 0x0 0x0 
0x7fff4290c6b8 0x7f33d6e3cbc4
HARAKIRI: -- wchan> poll_schedule_timeout
HARAKIRI !!! worker 4 status !!!
HARAKIRI [core 0] - POST /manager/_save_task since 1587660997
HARAKIRI !!! end of worker 4 status !!!
heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without 
response" method=POST path="/manager/_save_task"
DAMN ! worker 4 (pid: 11) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 4 (new pid: 14)
# FROM HERE ON, NOTHINGS WORKS ANYMORE
```

This behavior is consistent over several attempts: when the pid changes, the request fails. Even with a `pool_size = 1` in the `create_engine` function the issue persists. No issue instead is uwsgi is used with one process.

I am pretty sure it is my fault, there is something I don't know or I don't understand about how uwsgi and/or sqlalchemy work. Could you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, it seems that you need to share memory between workers. Check this question, it does not have a solution but it does explain ther reasons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133550/is-it-possible-to-share-memory-between-uwsgi-processes-running-flask-app.

Comment: @univerio I have been fooled by the unique id of the registry.

Answer (score 2):

What is hapeening is that you are trying to share memory between processes.
There are some exaplanations in these posts.

([is it possible to share memory between uwsgi processes running flask app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133550/is-it-possible-to-share-memory-between-uwsgi-processes-running-flask-app)).

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/45383617/11542053)

You can use an extra layer to store your sessions outsite of the app.

For that, you can use uWsgi's SharedArea(https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SharedArea.html) which is very low level or you can user other approaches like uWsgi's caching(https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Caching.html)

hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, I have tried to use the lazy-apps, so each process starts with "its own app" (I see in the log message that the app starts for each process and I have different current_app ids). However, the problem persists, but why? Aren't the apps independent in this case?

Comment: It happens because your apps is independent. If you make a request for the first time and it is handled by worker1, it will be created a session on worker1's  app, if your second request is handled by worker2, that does not have acess to worker's1 data, you'll be creating another session, this time in worker2.

Comment: I understand the conflict with multiple processes and ONE single app (as in my initial case), but with lazy_apps we have different processes --> different apps --> different registry --> different sessions so here it should not be a problem, as there is no session sharing, and the data is on the DB.

Comment: Are you closing your sessions? i often have problems with this. It seems like a deadlock is hapeening under the hood.